# How to filter unwanted points in a mask

Tags: python, opencv, filtering

I would like to detect a color then I work in HSV and use 3 treshold.

```
r,BGR = cap.read()
HSV = cv2.cvtColor(BGR, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lowerb = np.array([Hrange[0],Srange[0],Vrange[0]])
higherb = np.array([Hrange[1],Srange[1],Vrange[1]])

#Values comes from a trackbar

mask= cv2.inRange(HSV, lowerb, higherb)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(BGR,BGR, mask=mask)
```

H,S,V Ranges are like : 
[20,40], [50-170], [50,170]

As you see, the result is pixelised and I would like to unify every single area detected. (What is more white go white & what is more black go black)

Is there a Numpy or OpenCV2 function to do it?

[image: Mask]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inRange` gives you a binary image already, so there's no "more white" or "more black".
What you're looking for is morphological operations [Erode and Dilate](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html).

Alternatively, although arguably slower and not exactly the same thing, [median filter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=medianblur#medianblur) is also something worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will search this way! NOTE: with the "more white" I mean : "This pixel have more white neighbors than black ones. It should be white then!

Comment: In that case, median filter is your ideal candidate, because that statement of yours is itself the long and short of median filter (in binary images at least).

Comment: After some tests, it did EXACTLY what I wanted! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)